# What does "modulo equivalence relationship" mean?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, definition, self-learning

I am reading something on completion of metric spaces and it says:

> Let $\hat S$ be $\mathcal{C}$ modulo equivalence relationship of
>   co-Cauchy sequences. Where $\mathcal{C}$ is the set is all Cauchy
>   sequences on $S$.

I think I have encountered this in other contexts say in differential geometry, you see people drawing $\square \text{\~}$, defined as $\square$ modulo equivalence relationship. It seems to me this is pretty hand wavy but I don't understand what modulo mean in this context.

I tried [looking up this on google](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=q_OsVq_xDIqN8QfbsKTgAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=modulo%20equivalence%20relation) but unfortunately it gave me a bunch of stuff on number theory about modulo operator.

Comment: In lazy terms, its as though we treat everything that are *essentially* the same as though they were *actually* the same (where being essentially the same is defined by the equivalence relation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that $\hat{S}$ is the set of all **equivalence classes** of $\mathcal{C}$.  It assumes that we have in mind some specific equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathcal{C}$.

In other words, every element $s$ of $\hat{S}$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathcal{C}$.  The following two conditions hold:

- If $x \in s$ then we have $y \in s$ iff $x \sim y$
- For every $x \in \mathcal{C}$ there exists a unique $s \in \hat{S}$ with $x \in s$.